# How to configure mvn to download a npm dependency?

Tags: maven, npm, dependency-management

As part of the `mvn` build process, I do want to download/install a javascript file that is published as a npm package.

Currently that file was copied into `war/scripts/foobar.js` which means that if a newer version of the foobar is published to npm, we would have to manually download it from there and update our code.

Isn't possible to integrate this dependency in a similar way as java dependencies?

If you could provide me with one example of doing this it would be great.

Comment: Take a look at the https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use npm which involves incorporation of download/run of node and npm during your build. Other approach is to use maven itself and do not invoke any NodeJS processes.

For bigger projects where you have many npm dependencies which probably change a lot during development it's easier to use `package.json` descriptor and npm itself.

For smaller project where you just need on file I prefer to use simple maven plugin setup like this one for example:

```xml
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>download-babel-js</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wget</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>
https://coporate.nexus.instance/repository/npm-proxy/babel-standalone/-/babel-standalone-6.26.0.tgz
                            </url>
                            <unpack>true</unpack>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/babel</outputDirectory>
                            <md5>ed714bb8253fc6056902d8d0afd6b106</md5>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>download-redux</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wget</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>https://coporate.nexus.instance/repository/unpkg/redux@4.0.5/dist/redux.min.js</url>
                            <unpack>false</unpack>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/js</outputDirectory>
                            <md5>8e679dc2c2ea96e12f8189d85485927b</md5>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

To spice things up you can add minification and babel preprocessing to your scripts with following pure java maven plugins:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jarslab.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>babel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>js-transpile</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>babel</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <babelSrc>${project.basedir}/target/babel/package/babel.min.js</babelSrc>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/es6</sourceDir>
                            <targetDir>${project.build.directory}/js</targetDir>
                            <jsSourceIncludes>
                                <jsSourceInclude>*.js</jsSourceInclude>
                            </jsSourceIncludes>
                            <presets>es2015</presets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.blutorange</groupId>
                <artifactId>closure-compiler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-minify</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>

                            <!-- These are the defaults -->
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <baseSourceDir>${project.build.directory}</baseSourceDir>
                            <baseTargetDir>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</baseTargetDir>
                            <sourceDir>js</sourceDir>
                            <targetDir>js</targetDir>

                            <!-- List of files to process. May use wildcards. -->
                            <includes>
                                <include>my-script.js</include>
                            </includes>
                            <outputFilename>my-script.min.js</outputFilename>

                        </configuration>

                        <goals>
                            <goal>minify</goal>
                        </goals>

                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Hereby I would like to thank great plugin maintainers for their great job!

1. [Mickael](https://github.com/mickaelistria) and [others](https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin/graphs/contributors) from for google download plugin: https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin
2. [Milosz](https://github.com/milpol) for babel-maven-plugin: https://github.com/jarslab/babel-maven-plugin
3. [Andre](https://github.com/blutorange) for closure-compiler-maven-plugin: https://github.com/blutorange/closure-compiler-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1):

With an NPM resource, you would probably use the `npm install` to get it the proper way. I assume you do this already and then copy the resource over.

If that is the case, you could use just the maven-exec-plugin and just run the command before compiling, such as:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>npm-install</id>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <executable>npm</executable>
            <arguments>
              <argument>install</argument>
            </arguments>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I would not recommend depending on system resources so much as such build will easily fail on machines that does not have node/npm installed or have incorrect npm or node version. To run node from maven build it's better to use above mentioned https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin